# How to set environment variables in PowerShell to fetch a registered schema from Apollo Studio

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-federation

I'm following [Apollo Router Quickstart](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/router/quickstart/) documentation.

I am stuck on fetching the registered schema from Apollo Studio by setting environment variables. I'm using PowerShell and since this command is for Linux it doesn't work for windows.

```
$ APOLLO_KEY="..." APOLLO_GRAPH_REF="..." ./router
```

What command should I use for windows powershell?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do set it as,

```
$Env:APOLLO_KEY = "...."
$Env: APOLLO_GRAPH_REF = "...."
```